# Duplicate entry in Json file. C#

Tags: c#, json

I am creating console application that reads in bbc feeds and then it must create json files with news objects. It runs on the hour every hour. My problem is that it is duplicating the parent object but i don't understand why. The strange thing is that it works if you run it right on the hour but if you run it 5 minutes before the hour it creates this duplicate parent element.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get the starting time of app.
        DateTime startingTime = DateTime.Now;
        int minute = 1;
        int hoursRun = 0;
        bool folderCreated = false;
        int n = startingTime.AddHours(hoursRun).Hour;
        //this will be the folder path for feeds.
        string feedsFolderPath =  Environment.GetFolderPath(
                   System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\feeds";

        // uri for feeds.
        string bbcURI = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml";

        while (true)
        {
            // check the hour and if it is more than 1 minutes past the hour wait for the next hour.
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == startingTime.AddHours(hoursRun).Hour && DateTime.Now.Minute < minute)
            {
                //get feeds
                News bbcNewsFeed = ProcessFeedHelper.GetFeeds(bbcURI);

                // if this is the first run go ahead and create a json file.
                if (hoursRun == 0)
                {
                    if (!folderCreated) 
                    { 
                        ProcessFeedHelper.CreateFolder(feedsFolderPath);
                        folderCreated = true;
                    }
                    ProcessFeedHelper.CreateJsonFile(bbcNewsFeed, feedsFolderPath);

                }
                else
                {
                    //if it is the second time then we need to check for duplicates.
                    ProcessFeedHelper.RemoveDuplicatesFeeds(bbcNewsFeed, feedsFolderPath);
                    ProcessFeedHelper.CreateJsonFile(bbcNewsFeed, feedsFolderPath);
                }

                // if it is the 23rd hour then we need to reset the counter and detele all files in folder.
                if (hoursRun == 23)
                {
                    hoursRun = 0;

                    ProcessFeedHelper.DeleteFilesInDirectory(feedsFolderPath);
                }
                else
                {

                    //others increment the hoursrun.
                    hoursRun++;
                }


                bbcNewsFeed = null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

HelperClass

```
   public static News GetFeeds(String aURI)
    {
        News newsFeed;

            //instantiate xmlreader and point to uri
            using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(aURI))
            {
                //load  the feed into SyndicationFeed Object
                SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

                newsFeed = new News();

                List<NewsItem> newsItemList = new List<NewsItem>();


                foreach (var item in feed.Items)
                {
                    // BBC Feed parent element titles change throughout the day but I have not managed to get them all.
                    // Could potentially break however, the logic is correct.
                    // Here we create the parent element object.
                    if (item.Title.Text == "BBC News Channel" || item.Title.Text == "BBC News at 10")
                    {

                        newsFeed.title = item.Title.Text;
                        newsFeed.link = item.Id;
                        newsFeed.description = item.Summary.Text;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NewsItem newsItem = new NewsItem();
                        newsItem.title = item.Title.Text;
                        newsItem.link = item.Id;
                        newsItem.description = item.Summary.Text;
                        newsItem.publishDate = FormatDate(item.PublishDate.ToString());

                        //Add it to parent object.
                        newsItemList.Add(newsItem);
                    }
                }

                newsFeed.items = newsItemList;
                //close reader once we have finished reading feed and return feed object.
                reader.Close();

            }
            return newsFeed;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a folder at a specified path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aPath"></param>
    public static void CreateFolder(string aPath)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(aPath);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Json formatted file based on a news object passed through.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aNews"></param>
    /// <param name="aPath"></param>
    public static void CreateJsonFile(News aNews, string aPath)
    {

            string filePath = aPath + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH") + ".json";


            //serialises objects in news Object and appends a file.
            string jsonFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aNews, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

            aNews = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(jsonFile);

            jsonFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aNews, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);


            File.AppendAllText(@filePath, jsonFile);

            Console.WriteLine(jsonFile);


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes Duplicate news articles in new feeds if they are already stored in files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aNews"></param>
    /// <param name="aPath"></param>
    public static void RemoveDuplicatesFeeds(News aNews, string aPath)
    {
        try
        {
            //get paths to all files.
            string[] filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(aPath);

            List<News> newsInFiles = new List<News>();
            News newsInFile;

            // loop through files in directory.
            foreach (string aFile in filesInDirectory)
            {
                //Read files file and deserialise the news object putting it in a news collection.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(aFile);
                string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                newsInFile = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(fileContent);

                newsInFiles.Add(newsInFile);
                reader.Close();
            }
            //only go in here if there is the recent feed has news items.
            if (aNews.items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (News aNewsInFile in newsInFiles)
                {
                    // put news list into new news list so the next loop doesn't crash.
                    List<NewsItem> tempNewsList = new List<NewsItem>(aNews.items);
                    foreach (NewsItem aNewsItemFromCurrentFeed in tempNewsList)
                    {
                        //check that the current news item is not already in files saved.
                        var newsItemAlreadyExists = from nItems in aNewsInFile.items
                                                    where nItems.title == aNewsItemFromCurrentFeed.title
                                                    where nItems.publishDate == aNewsItemFromCurrentFeed.publishDate
                                                    where nItems.link == aNewsItemFromCurrentFeed.link
                                                    where nItems.description == aNewsItemFromCurrentFeed.description
                                                    select nItems;
                        // if item already stored in file then we must remove it as we don't want it.
                        if (newsItemAlreadyExists.First() != null)
                        {
                            if (aNews.items.Contains(aNewsItemFromCurrentFeed))
                            {
                                aNews.items.Remove(aNewsItemFromCurrentFeed);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Error");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes all the files in a directory(path specified in parameter).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="directoryPath"></param>
    public static void DeleteFilesInDirectory(string directoryPath)
    {
        try
        {
            //create files collection and directory object.
            List<FileInfo> importFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
            DirectoryInfo tempDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);

            //get all files in directory.
            importFiles.AddRange(tempDirectory.GetFiles());

            //if the number of files in the directory are greater than zero then delete them.
            if (importFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < importFiles.Count; i++)
                    importFiles[i].Delete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Error");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Formats a string to ddd, mm yyyy hh:ss gmt
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aDate"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static String FormatDate(String aDate)
    {
        try
        {
            //split string 
            char[] delimiters = { ' ', ',', ':', '/' };
            string[] tokens = aDate.Split(delimiters);
            int year = int.Parse(tokens[2]);
            int month = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
            int day = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
            int hh = int.Parse(tokens[3]);
            int mm = int.Parse(tokens[4]);
            int ss = int.Parse(tokens[5]);

            //create date time object. and add gmt to end of string.
            DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day, hh, mm, ss);
            return date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Error");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

parent class

```
class News
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string link{ get; set; }
    public string description{ get; set; }        
    public IList<NewsItem> items{ get; set; }


}
```

child class

```
 class NewsItem
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string publishDate { get; set; }

}
```

File example (not suppose to have end part)

```
  {
  "title": "BBC News Channel",
   "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10318089",
   "description": "Britain's most-watched news channel, delivering breaking        news and analysis all day, every day.",
     "items": [
   {
      "title": "Dover ferry port chaos leads to 14-hour traffic jams",
      "description": "Delays at the Port of Dover have caused up to 14-hour tailbacks on the A20 /M20 with Kent Police warning disruption could last for another two days.",
       "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-kent-36873632",
      "publishDate": "Sat, 23 Jul 2016 19:38:36 GMT"
   }, ]
 }    {
   "title": "BBC News Channel",
    "link": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10318089",
   "description": "Britain's most-watched news channel, delivering breaking news and analysis all day, every day.",
  "items": []
 }
```

Comment: If you run it 5 minutes before the hour, I would expect it to do nothing for about 23 hours... is my understanding wrong? If you start it at 8:55, I would think your condition is (pseudo-code) "if hour == 8 and minute == 0" which won't happen for another 23 hours and 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue *might* be the race condition here:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == startingTime.AddHours(hoursRun).Hour && DateTime.Now.Minute < minute)
```

Suppose you start the program at 8:59, so as I pointed out in my comment above, it's looking for the hour to be 8 and the minute to be 0. You'd think that wouldn't happen for 23 hours or so, but...

Imagine that at 8:59:59.9999, this condition is checked `DateTime.Now.Hour == startingTime.AddHours(hoursRun).Hour` and returns true, because the hour is currently 8. So execution proceeds to check the next condition: `DateTime.Now.Minute < minute`. Time has passed, so it's 9:00 at the time that condition is checked. So both conditions are true, and code is executed. (A file gets created called `2016-07-23-09.json`.)

Now `hoursRun` is incremented, so it's now 9.

Next iteration of the loop, the time is something like 9:00:05. Both conditions are true (hour is 9, minute is 0), so the code runs again, appending to the same file (`2016-07-23-09.json`).

If my hunch is right, probably the smallest fix would be to do this, which makes sure you're checking the hour and minute component of the same time:

```
while (true)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    if (now.Hour == startingTime.AddHours(hoursRun).Hour && now.Minute < minute)
    {
```

I'd also recommend putting a sleep statement in that `while` loop... you're probably burning a significant amount of CPU in this tight busy-loop.

**EDIT**

Oh, also, you probably didn't mean to wait 23 hours in the first place. :-) You might just use a `+1` everywhere as an easy fix (though it means if you run the program right at 8:00, it's going to wait until 9:00 to write the first file).

**EDIT 2**

If you don't care about running "on the hour," this may be a simpler way to structure the loop:

```
DateTime lastRun = DateTime.MinValue;

while (true)
{
    // sleep for 10 minutes at a time until an hour has passed
    while ((DateTime.UtcNow - lastRun) < TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }

    // do work in here

    // remember the last time we did work
    lastRun = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after testing this morning this is the case. A bit shortsighted solution by myself. However, the serialisation was the bigger problem. I have decided the create file section into the main class where, so far, it does not appear to be happening. I think this was happening because it was creating a local copy for the method stack and still looking at the heap. Then it serialised both. I understand this may be well off mark but it helps me sleep otherwise.